# speed up application loading with AdMob (Android)

Tags: android, performance, admob

I've added AdMod ads to my app. The point is that now the app is loading a notable time and the adds get showed first than my app. My app is local it doesn't require internet connection or any external call. The app actually is in js (phonegap converted). Is it possible to load my app 1st and then the adds? Is it possible to speed up overall loading process?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a callback that phonegap implements once its view is loaded. And then call `loadAd()` method within that callback !

This will delay loading you ad !